# SP making Access run slow?

Tags: 2007

I'd like to know if you can help me. There is a strange program running a lot and our IT people says it may to do with SharePoint and the IT people feel it is 'distracting' our server.

it is     webempsch

Do you know what that is?  I did not willingly connect SP to Access is this making our Access Database run slow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm  going  to  say  that  it  is  probably  a  **Web**-based **Emp** loyee **Sch** edule  database. This isn't anything inside of SP so I think one of your developers must have created this object.

Good luck!